# PHP object is not being created

Tags: php, mysql

I have received the following error:"**Fatal error: Call to a member function *session_type()* on a non-object**".
Supposedly I'm not creating an object in the variable "**$tabsessiontype2**". I don't see the reason why the object isn't created. Thanks for you help.

Here is my TeacherController.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['search']) && $_POST['sessiontype_name']){
        $tabsessiontype2=Db::getInstance()->select_session_type2($_POST['sessiontype_name']);
        if($tabsessiontype2->session_type()=='X'){
            $view='teacher.php';
        }
        elseif($tabsessiontype2->session_type()=='XO'){
            $view='teacherxo.php';
        }
        elseif($tabsessiontype2->session_type()=='note'){
            $view='teachernote.php';
        }
    }
```

This is the function I call:

```
public function select_session_type2($name_session_type) {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM session_types WHERE session_types.name_session_type='$name_session_type'";
    $result = $this->_db->query($query); 
    $tableau = array();
    if ($result->rowcount()!=0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch()) {       
            $tableau[] = new Sessiontype($row->code_session_type,$row->name_session_type,$row->quarter_session_type,$row->code_lesson,$row->session_type);
        }
    }
    return $tableau;
}
```

Here is the SessionType class:

```
class SessionType{
    private $_code_session_type;
    private $_name_session_type;
    private $_quarter_session_type;
    private $_code_lesson;
    private $_session_type;

public function __construct($code_session_type,$name_session_type, $quarter_session_type, $code_lesson,$session_type){
    $this->_code_session_type = $code_session_type;
    $this->_name_session_type = $name_session_type;
    $this->_quarter_session_type = $quarter_session_type;
    $this->_code_lesson = $code_lesson;
    $this->_session_type = $session_type;
}

public function code_session_type(){
    return $this->_code_session_type;       
}   

public function name_session_type(){
    return $this->_name_session_type;
}

public function quarter_session_type(){
    return $this->_lastname;
}

public function code_lesson(){
    return $this->_email_student;
}

public function session_type(){
    return $this->_session_type;
}
```

}

Comment: `$tabsessiontype2` is an object of Class `Db` Class `Db` does not have a method called `session_type` that is a method of Class `SessionType`

Comment: select_session_type2 is supposed to hold the object of type 'SessionType', then session_type is called from the object. @RiggsFolly

Comment: So what does `Db:getInstance()` do and what does it return

Comment: @RiggsFolly It calls the function which is in the Db class, which allows me to access the **select_session_type2** function.

Comment: But does it? Lets have a squint at it

Comment: `select_session_type2()` returns an `array` of multiple `SessionType` objects. Ergo, `$tabsessiontype2` is an array of objects, and not an object itself.

Comment: Ok you know best

Comment: @rickdenhaan Right, so I should find a way to put a single object into **$tabsessiontype2** , or do you think there is a way to extract the 'session_type' from this array of objects ?

Comment: That would depend entirely on the logic of your application. You could edit the method to only return one object, you could call `session_type()` only on `$tabsessiontype2[0]` (after checking if it exists), you could loop through all objects in the array and call the method on all of them. It really depends on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the function `select_session_type2` is returning an array:

```
$tableau = array();
if ($result->rowcount()!=0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {       
        $tableau[] = new Sessiontype($row->code_session_type,$row->name_session_type,$row->quarter_session_type,$row->code_lesson,$row->session_type);
    }
}
return $tableau;
```

and you are expecting an object:

```
$tabsessiontype2=Db::getInstance()->select_session_type2($_POST['sessiontype_name']);
if($tabsessiontype2->session_type()=='X'){
    $view='teacher.php';
}
```